# Auto block IP's with iptables if rate is over 100 in 1 minute?

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

How can i auto block IP's with iptables if the connection number is over 100 in 1 minute on all ports and all protocols (TCP, UDP)?

Offtopic: OpenSSH disconnects me after a few seconds in debian 7, and on Ubuntu Server 12.10 x64 that does not happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question belongs on serverfault, and that you may have an answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/419784/how-to-automatically-and-temporarily-block-an-ip-address-making-too-many-hits-on).

Comment: Thanks for answering! But how can I do it on all ports? @micke

Comment: I'm not familiar with iptables, but I'm sure you'll get some help if you ask the question on "serverfault" or "askubuntu" instead. In addition you'll get 100 points in association bonus. :-) Good luck!